# How to count value from column in a row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

How to count all the columns in a row from a table?
I'm having trouble combining of queries, I really need help.
Someone help me.

My Table looks like this;

jhsf2

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|Stud_ID|M1|T1|W1|TH1|F1|M2|T2|W2|TH2|F2| 
|1022234|  |P |P |P  |P |A |P |P | P | P|
|1045978|  |P |P |P  |P |P |P |P | P | P|
+---------------------------------------+
```

And I want the result like this if I have the query to do that.
I want to count from M1 to F2 that have a value not Null and it's something like this.

jhsf2

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|Stud_ID|Count(M1,T1,W1,TH1,F1,M2,T2,W2,TH2,F2) |
|1022234|                  9                    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

OR I want to use WHERE query in mysql, i don't know the query but it's just like this.

```
Select Stud_ID,M1,T1,W1,TH1,F1,M2,T2,W2,TH2 from jhsf2 
WHERE Stud_ID = "131418100008" 
and M1,T1,W1,TH1,F1,M2,T2,W2,TH2 T2, = "P"


+-----------------------------------------------+
|Stud_ID|Count(M1,T1,W1,TH1,F1,M2,T2,W2,TH2,F)  |
|1022234|                  8                    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Which question is the real question?

Comment: Maybe `PIVOT` then `COUNT`?

Comment: If M1 is related to M2 etc etc, your DB design is broke

Comment: See normalisation. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can count the values by adding up booleans:

```
select stud_id,
       ( (m1 = 'P') + (m2 = 'P') + . . .
       ) as cnt
from jhsf2;
```

Note:  Having multiple columns that contain essentially an array is not a good data structure in SQL.  Normally, you would want one row per `stud_id` and column value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by checking the value not null and count of asterisk (all)

```
        Select count(*) from     
         jhsf2 WHERE Stud_ID !=null and M1!=null and ..
         .......
```

..........rest all columns which u want to check that it's values are fine or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clever enough to create a select to do the job but you can do it in code.
I have guessed the data type of Student ID as Long. Adjust the code if it is something else.

```
Private Sub GetCount()
        Dim dictStudents As New Dictionary(Of Long, Integer)
        Dim itgNonNullCount As Integer = 0
        Dim strQuery As String = "Select * from jhsf2"
        Using cn As New MySqlConnection("your connection string")
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand With {
                    .Connection = cn,
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                    .CommandText = strQuery}
                cn.Open()
                Using dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    If dr.HasRows Then
                        While dr.Read
                            'Loop through each column
                            For i As Integer = 1 To 10 'number of columns -1
                                If dr.GetValue(i) IsNot DBNull.Value Then
                                    itgNonNullCount += 1
                                End If
                            Next
                            'Add the student ID and count to the dictionary
                            dictStudents.Add(dr.GetInt64(0), itgNonNullCount)
                            'reset the count back to zero for the next record
                            itgNonNullCount = 0
                        End While
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```